# Cypress: create object and re use object values in the tests

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to Cypress. I would appreciate any tips and help. My test:

1. Go to the page
2. parse Response from the server
3. take any item from that response
4. and then I want to save that item into an object for later use in the tests.

```
cy.wait('@pageLoaded').then(({ response }) => {
            expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            
            let i = randomItem();
            
            //Create an object
            const Item = {
                Id: response.body.items[i].id,
                IpuCode: response.body.items[i].ipuCode,
                Description: response.body.items[i].description,
                PackSize: response.body.items[i].packSize,
                PackType: response.body.items[i].packType,
            };
            
           //Here I'm getting the expected array
            cy.log(Item);
            
        })
        //And here I want to re-use it
        
        cy.addItemToShoppingCart(Item.value(IpuCode), pharmacyId, Item.value(Id), currentDateTime);
```

So, I have tryed

```
cy.addItemToShoppingCart(Item.value(IpuCode), pharmacyId, Item.value(Id), currentDateTime);
```

Th result: Item is not defined

OR

```
 cy.addItemToShoppingCart(Item.IpuCode, pharmacyId, Item.Id, currentDateTime);
```

The result: Item is not defined

I also, have working way to get values and use it

```
            cy.wait('@pageLoaded').then(({ response }) => {
                expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                
                let i = randomItem();
                let ItemGmsCode = response.body.items[i].gmsCode;
                cy.log(ItemGmsCode);
                cy.wrap(ItemGmsCode).as('itemGmsCode');
            })
```

But I don't like that every time, I have to wrap the command in a block

```
            cy.get('@itemGmsCode').then((gmsCode) => {
                //do soemthing
            })
```

Or do I want the impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in mechanism for saving data within a test is the [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases) which you would use in your code like this

```js
cy.wait('@pageLoaded').then(({ response }) => {
  ...
  cy.wrap({
    id: response.body.items[i].id,
    ipuCode: response.body.items[i].ipuCode,
    description: response.body.items[i].description,
    packSize: response.body.items[i].packSize,
    packType: response.body.items[i].packType,
  }.as('item')
})

// later in the same test

cy.get('@item').then(item => {
  cy.addItemToShoppingCart(item.ipuCode, pharmacyId, item.id, currentDateTime)
})
```

In Javascript the convention is to use camel case, which means the first char of an identifier is lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and yes, I will take your point into account about variables name

Comment: I'm almost sure `this.item.ipuCode` will not work as this value is not yet computed by the time when it's evaluated.
you have to use `then` callback anyway